# When is the fundamental group of a locally symmetric space residually finite?

Tags: group-theory, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology

A space with [residually finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group) fundamental group has the nice property that the $l^2$-betti number can be computed as the limit of the usual betti numbers. Of course, there are other interesting connections.

For example, finite groups, free groups and fundamental groups of $3$-manifolds are residually finite.

My question is: Are there some conditions under which $\pi_1(M)$ is residually finite for a locally symmetric space $M$ ?

Comment: Look at p. 512 of Bridson-Häfliger.  It doesn't exactly answer your question, but it's related.  They state that quotients of symmetric spaces of finite type have residually finite fundamental group.  They also give references for examples of NPC spaces whose fundamental groups are not residually finite.

Comment: You need finite generation too. Now use linearity of the ambient Lie group.

Comment: Isometry groups of symmetric spaces are linear Lie groups. So the fundamental group of a locally symmetric space is residually finite as it's finitely generated. In the infinitely generated case, I'm not aware of non-residually finite examples, but they might exist (I guess this boils down to finding a discrete non-residually finite subgroup in a linear semisimple Lie group).

Comment: This sounds interesting and I'd love to understand it. However, after exessive searching, I have still not been able to find out why the isometry $I(M)$ of a symmetric space is linear and why $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely generated. @YCor Can you maybe suggest a general reference for symmetric spaces for this regards? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, does the argument that $I(m)$ is a linear group work with the adjoint representation?

Comment: The standard reference is Helgason's book on differential geometry, lie groups and symmetric spaces. For a symmetric space $X$ there a canonical decomposition $X=C\times E\times N$, $C$ compact, $E$ Euclidean, $N$ noncompact type, so Isometry group splits as a product of Isom group of each. Isom(C) is a compact Lie group, thus linear. Isom(E) is clearly linear. Isom(C) is a semisimple group with trivial center (and finitely many components), thus is linear as well (through its adjoint representation).